# iterate over PersistentVector of objects in clojure

Tags: arrays, json, vector, clojure, persistent

I am new to Clojure and I am trying to iterate over a PersistentVector of objects, which looks like below when I print in logs.

```
[{name John, email john@example.com} {name Peter, email peter@example.com}]
```

when I print (type myData) it tells me it is of type clojure.lang.PersistentVector

I have to iterate over this vector, extract email from each object inside it at a time and invoke another function.

It looks very simple, I looked at many samples and questions, but nothing seem to work for me :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

If you don't care about the objects ("maps" in Clojure speak) and only want to collect the emails and apply a function over them, you can create a simple function just to extract the emails into another collection and then use any function over the collection of emails:

```clj
(def items
  [{"name" "John", "email" "john@example.com"} {"name" "Peter", "email" "peter@example.com"}])

(defn get-email [m]
  (get m "email"))

(mapv get-email items)
;; returns: ["john@example.com", "peter@example.com"]
```

You can use function composition to the create a function that turns into upper case (using `upper-case` from `clojure.string`) the result of getting the email: (note the ordering in `comp`):

```clj
(mapv (comp clojure.string/upper-case get-email) items)
;; returns ["JOHN@EXAMPLE.COM" "PETER@EXAMPLE.COM"]
```

If you want to obtain a similar collection but with the email field updated, you can use `update-in`:

```clj
(mapv (fn [m] (update-in m ["email"] clojure.string/upper-case)) items)
;; Applies `upper-case` to the "email" path of each map identified by `m`.
;; returns: [{"name" "John", "email" "JOHN@EXAMPLE.COM"} {"name" "Peter", "email" "PETER@EXAMPLE.COM"}]
```

There are more elegant ways to do the same work using other techniques (anonymous functions, strs destructuring) but I think the ones above are simpler to understand if you are new to Clojure.